# How to call a method that needs a Func<T> with an lambda Expression argument

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates, expression, func

I know that I can call a generic method that takes an lambda Expression directly.
For example in my code below I can call this method directly but this will not achieve what I need:
    GetAllItemsFromTableAsync(x => x.ID =3)

What I would like is to pass a generic method as a delegate and I would like to pass that method (or derivatives of it) a lambda expression argument (a database filter actually) which will eventually call the GetAllItemsFromTableAsync method, providing the necessary filter expression.

Is it possible to pass a method as a delegate AND provide an lambda expression for that same method when it takes such as a parameter?  In my code you will see two example regions, one works currently (though it is very much simplified from the original code, I have not compiled it but think it conveys the basic idea) the other marked "does not work" is what I would like to achieve in some fashion or another if it is even possible.  Currently it is not since I can not figure out how to reference the argument passed in order to daisy chain it to the other method.  Can this be done?

I am somewhat new to lambda and truthfully am still trying wrap my head around it all.  Any help would be very appreciated.

```
           #region This model does work currently (overly simplified for example purposes)
    /// <summary>
    /// Loads the various controls on the page that need special processing
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected async Task RefreshControls()
    {
        await LoadPickerAsync<Car, ViewModel<Car>, List<Car>>(
            this.GetPropertyInfo(x => x.AvailableColors),
            this.GetPropertyInfo(y => y.ColorIndex),
            this.GetPropertyInfo(z => z.Color),
            LoadFromDBAsync<Colors, List<Colors>>);

        await LoadPickerAsync<Truck, ViewModel<Truck>, List<Truck>>(
            this.GetPropertyInfo(x => x.AvailableColors),
            this.GetPropertyInfo(y => y.ColorIndex),
            this.GetPropertyInfo(z => z.Color),
            LoadFromDBAsync<Colors, List<Colors>>);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method is first stop in the load process.  It sorts out the properties and then calls the 
    /// delegate method (in this example LoadFromDBAsync) to perform the actual loading of the picker list.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TColItemType"></typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TViewModel"></typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TCollection"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="collectionProperty"></param>
    /// <param name="indexProperty"></param>
    /// <param name="objectProperty"></param>
    /// <param name="collectionLoaderAsync"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected virtual async Task<TCollection> LoadPickerAsync<TColItemType, TViewModel, TCollection>(
            PropertyInfo collectionProperty,
            PropertyInfo indexProperty,
            PropertyInfo objectProperty,
            Func<Task<TCollection>> collectionLoaderAsync) 
        //Note I need to know how to pass a filter to the method here such as "x => x.ID = 2"
                where TCollection : List<TColItemType>
    {
        //Do some special stuff with the properties

        //Actually Load the picker
        if (await collectionLoaderAsync() != default(TCollection))
        {
            //do something useful, set a flag etc...
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// This method would be within each view model and may be totally different from one view
    /// model to the next and even some controls may use their own method as long as the 
    /// basic signature remains the same
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TColItemType"></typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TCollection"></typeparam>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected virtual async Task<TCollection> LoadFromDBAsync<TColItemType, TCollection>()
        //I'd like to add a way for this method to pass a filter: "Expression<Func<TColItemType, bool>> filter = null"
            where TCollection : List<TColItemType>, new()
            where TColItemType : new()
    {
        //if I add the argument parameter to the method I can not figure out how to make the call 
        //to this method in LoadPickerAsync method above
        //Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null,

        //do some more stuff with the loading of the items into the picker

        //Call the method to load the data and return
        //note that "fitler" is only applicable if I can add the parameter above
        return (TCollection)await GetAllItemsFromTableAsync<TColItemType>(); 
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Gets all data from the database table with the specified filter
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="filter"></param>
    /// <param name="cancelToken"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected async Task<List<TColItemType>> GetAllItemsFromTableAsync<TColItemType>() where TColItemType : new()
    {
        //Do some prep work and null checks before calling the actual database method
        //

        //Call the database method to obtain the data
        return await database.GetAllWithChildrenAsync<TColItemType>(recursive: true);
    }
    #endregion This model does work currently (overly simplified for example purposes)


    #region Does NOT work
    /// <summary>
    /// Loads the various controls on the page that need special processing
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected async Task RefreshControls()
    {
        await LoadPickerAsync<Car, ViewModel<Car>, List<Car>>(
            this.GetPropertyInfo(x => x.AvailableColors),
            this.GetPropertyInfo(y => y.ColorIndex),
            this.GetPropertyInfo(z => z.Color),
            LoadFromDBAsync<Colors, List<Colors>>(x => x.ID == 4));

        await LoadPickerAsync<Truck, ViewModel<Truck>, List<Truck>>(
            this.GetPropertyInfo(x => x.AvailableColors),
            this.GetPropertyInfo(y => y.ColorIndex),
            this.GetPropertyInfo(z => z.Color),
            LoadFromDBAsync<Colors, List<Colors>>(x => x.ID == 3));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method is first stop in the load process.  It sorts out the properties and then calls the 
    /// delegate method (in this example LoadFromDBAsync) to perform the actual loading of the picker list.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TColItemType"></typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TViewModel"></typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TCollection"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="collectionProperty"></param>
    /// <param name="indexProperty"></param>
    /// <param name="objectProperty"></param>
    /// <param name="collectionLoaderAsync"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected virtual async Task<TCollection> LoadPickerAsync<TColItemType, TViewModel, TCollection>(
            PropertyInfo collectionProperty,
            PropertyInfo indexProperty,
            PropertyInfo objectProperty,
            Func<Expression<Func<TColItemType, bool>>, Task<TCollection>> collectionLoaderAsync) 
            //Note I need to know how to pass a filter argument to the method here such as "x => x.ID = 2"
                where TCollection : List<TColItemType>
    {
        //Do some special stuff with the properties

        //With this overload example I can not figure out how to reference the argument passed in inorder to 
        //subsequently pass that argument when making the call to the method

        //Actually Load the picker
        await collectionLoaderAsync(filterArg);
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// This method would be within each view model and may be totally different from one view
    /// model to the next and even some controls may use their own method as long as the 
    /// basic signature remains the same
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TColItemType"></typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TCollection"></typeparam>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected virtual async Task<TCollection> LoadFromDBAsync<TColItemType, TCollection>(
        Expression<Func<TColItemType, bool>> filter = null)
        //I'd like to add a way for this method to pass a filter: "Expression<Func<TColItemType, bool>> filter = null"
            where TCollection : List<TColItemType>, new()
            where TColItemType : new()
    {
        //if I add the argument parameter to the method I can not figure out 
        //how to make the call to this method in LoadPickerAsync method above
        //Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null,

        //do some more stuff with the loading of the items into the picker

        //Call the method to load the data and return
        //note that "fitler" is only applicable if I can add the parameter above
        return GetAllItemsFromTableAsync<TColItemType>(filter); 
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Gets all data from the database table with the specified filter
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="filter"></param>
    /// <param name="cancelToken"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected async Task<List<TColItemType>> GetAllItemsFromTableAsync<TColItemType>(
            Expression<Func<TColItemType, bool>> filter = null) where TColItemType : Car, new()
    {
        //Do some prep work and null checks before calling the actual database method
        //

        //Call the database method to obtain the data
        return await database.GetAllWithChildrenAsync<TColItemType>(recursive: true, filter: filter);
    }


    #endregion Does NOT work
```

Comment: You really need to simplify this code by about 99%. People will otherwise not take the time to read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write `LoadFromDBAsync<Colors, List<Colors>>(x => x.ID == 4)`, this will *call* your LoadFromDBAsync method. If you want to pass it as delegate, you need to pass a lambda expression instead:

```
await LoadPickerAsync<Car, ViewModel<Car>, List<Car>>(
  this.GetPropertyInfo(x => x.AvailableColors),
  this.GetPropertyInfo(y => y.ColorIndex),
  this.GetPropertyInfo(z => z.Color),
  () => LoadFromDBAsync<Colors, List<Colors>>(x => x.ID == 4));
```

**Background:** The shorthand notation in your first example, passing a "method group" (i.e. `LoadFromDBAsync<Colors, List<Colors>>` to the `collectionLoaderAsync` parameter, works only if the method has the same signature at the parameter type (i.e. `Func<Task<TCollection>>`). In your second example, the signature does not match because of the extra `filter` parameter. Therefore, the above full lambda notation is required.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Such a simple solution.  I figured I was on the right path somehow.  Your answer worked flawlessly.